# Why calculating percentage from double variables return 0.00

Tags: java, double

The following code will return 0.00 no matter what the argument variables are.

```
public double updateConjustion(double numberOfAuditors, double numberOfTotalAuditors){
    double conjustion = ((numberOfAuditors/numberOfTotalAuditors)*100);
    return conjustion;
}
```

Comment: are you sure `numberOfAuditors` and `numberOfTotalAuditors` are doubles (and not int or some other integer type)?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the usage of this function? (Both the call and what you do with the result.) The name of the function sounds like it's supposed to update something; maybe the caller assumes that it does. Do you have a variable called `conjustion` somewhere else?

Comment: yes it updates a double variable conjustion. I've changed the function a lil bit to make it presentable in the question. it is actually a void function and changes the value of the variable conjustion every time it is executed.

Comment: the variable conjustion is an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet seems to work for me.

```
public class Test{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(updateConjustion(1.0, 200.0));
        System.out.println(updateConjustion(0.5, 5000.0));
        System.out.println(updateConjustion(0.99, 3000.0));
        System.out.println(updateConjustion(1.0, 3000.0));
        System.out.println(updateConjustion(1, 50));
     }

     public static double updateConjustion(double numberOfAuditors, double numberOfTotalAuditors){
       double conjustion = ((numberOfAuditors/numberOfTotalAuditors)*100.0);
       return conjustion;
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
0.5                                                                       
0.01                                                                      
0.033                                                                     
0.03333333333333333                                                       
2.0
```

**__UPDATE__**

So I don't think anything is wrong with the method you provided. You should look elsewhere to find the root of the problem. Possible places to look for are:

- How you use this method
- How you use the result of that method

If you share these areas with us, we could provide more help.

Comment: "Works for me" is not an answer to the question. The OP has a problem; simply saying "no you don't" doesn't make the problem go away.

Comment: Well, what I am trying to tell him is that his problem is not in the above method. He should look else where.

Comment: You didn't make that very clear. And besides, that should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I have just done that. And it is hard to write code within comment.